# Does the size of a charcoal affect the heat energy produced?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity, heat-conduction

It's established that the more charcoal used to start a fire, the more heat is going to be produced since there are more carbon atoms reacting with the oxygen to undergo combustion. However, are there any other justification as to why this happens? Or if there's an extension of the elaboration provided above?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

As a chunk of charcoal briquette burns, the chemical reactions are occurring at the surface of the chunk since there is no oxygen *inside* the chunk. Therefore, the more *surface area* a pile of briquettes has, the *faster* it will generate heat, and the hotter the pile will burn.

Briquette manufacturers know this, and they size the briquettes so as to produce a convenient heat generation rate for cooking on a grille. This is why almost all the bagged briquettes on the market are the same size.

Fast generation of heat in a pile that you are trying to start means there's little time for the heat to escape the pile, which in turn means the fire will spread more quickly to all briquettes in the pile and so the pile will begin burning more quickly.

BBQ grille manufacturers know this, which is why they furnish a *briquette starter* which is a cylindrical tube that you fill with briquettes and light from the bottom.  The heat released by the first briquettes to ignite is confined to the inside of the cylinder and hence used to start the rest of the briquettes.

There was once a competition to see which method of starting a BBQ briquette pile was the fastest. The (very dangerous!) winning method was invented by a team of guys (it's always guys!) who poured liquid oxygen onto a briquette pile in a Weber BBQ grille and lit it off. Because there was plenty of O2 soaked into each briquette, the burn rate was not surface-area-limited and the pile instantly exploded into a huge geyser of flame, which was captured on camera.

DO NOT try this at home!

Comment: (+1) For the answer and reminding me of that wonderful video! Not much left of the grill! Maybe someone will ask about the exploding dead whale next! ;-)